# How can I rewrite URLs on my Vercel-hosted app to hide query parameters and display a cleaner URL?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel

How can I rewrite the URL of my query page from "/query?data=query_data" to "/query/query_data" on my Vercel-hosted app without displaying "?data=" on the URL using either vercel.json or Nuxt.js rewrites?

The user has a Vue file named `query.vue`, which displays query data when the URL `"/query?data=query_data"` is visited. However, the user wants to display the query data on the URL without showing the query parameter (`?data=`). The desired URL structure is `"/query/query_data"`. The user has tried using `vercel.json` and Nuxt.js rewrites to achieve this, but neither method has worked for them. The application is hosted on Vercel.

Comment: Have you tried dynamic route matching with vue-router? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: I tried but it not worked as I want, I found the url as /query/?data=abcd not as a /query/abcd/ here's the code of router.js "import one from '~/page/query.vue'

export default () => ({
  routes: [
    { 
      path: '/page/query/:data', 
      component: query, 
      name: 'query'
    }
  ],
})"

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your use case. Are you trying to convert incoming query strings to params? Like user browses to /query/?data=abcd and they are redirected to /query/abcd ? If so you can use a beforeEach route guard that looks for a query string then do a router.replace call to update it. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards